# Redirect an https URL to an internal web app

Tags: node.js, iis, url-rewriting, http-redirect, windows-server-2019

I currently have an https domain **https://example.com** hosted in a Windows Server R2019 machine. I am also developing a web application in Node.js in my laptop that will, in the future, be installed in the server.

Say I want to share my app with external parties that require https. During this test stage I will keep the web app in my laptop, instead of installing it in the server. In order to use the same SSL certificate assigned to **https://example.com**, would I be able to configure IIS to redirect a certain URL like **https://example.com/myapp** to my laptop's internal IP/PORT (192.168.xxx.xxx:port) where the app is hosted?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Configure the IIS as reverse proxy. A redirect just tells the client to connect to your internal ip, which does not work.

Comment: @Marc thank you for pointing that. So, after the reverse proxy configuration, I will be able to receive HTTPS requests that will be forwarded to my internal ip. But, how about  sending HTTP requests FROM the internal app? The request needs to be sent to IIS, which will send an HTTPS to the destination URL? Is it possible to configure this?

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).